# У меня выходит ошибка помогите

Tags: python

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Програмирование\Tkinter\Приложение\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import Image
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 36, in <module>
    import tempfile
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Програмирование\random.py", line 7, in <module>
    num=random()*8
        ^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

А вот сам код:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x800")
im=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Fortnite_S1.png")
btn=Button(root, image=im, height=5, width=4)
btn.grid
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Имена файлов не должны совпадать с именами библиотек переименуйте созданный вами файл `random.py`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В этом коде нет указанной строчки.

Comment: В ошибке же написано, что проблема в файле C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Програмирование\random.py переименуйте его

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникла из-за того, что вы создали файл с именем `random.py`,
что привело к тому, что импортированный модуль `random` ссылается на ваш файл `random.py`, а не на оригинальный модуль `random`.

Вам нужно переименовать файл `random.py` во что-то другое, например, `my_random.py`. После этого вы должны снова импортировать модуль random в своем коде.

Comment: Простите, но у файла имя main.py

Comment: сам файл может и main.py, но нет ли файлов random.py в папке "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Програмирование" и вложенных в нее?

Answer (score -1):

Вы целый модуль (файл, библиотека) пытаетесь вызвать как функцию, вызовите у этого модуля какой-нибудь метод, напимер, random.randint(); random.choice(). В Вашем случае можно попробовать random.random() - возвращает случайное число от 0 до 1. Это судя из ошибки, а вот что в коде не так, я не знаю, попробуйте библиотеки переустановить. А еще вы забыли скобки - btn.grid()